# Is there any implied meaning betwwen "n + of all sorts" and "all sorts of + n"?

Tags: foreign-phrases

1: There were all sorts of industry in the uplands of Zurich

2: You shall have gold as well, and jewels of all sorts

May I use "industries of all sorts" in the first sentence and "all sorts of jewels" in the second sentece?

So whether I can conclude "n + of all sorts = n+ of every sort and kind = all sorts of + n"?

Is there any implied meaning betwwen "n + of all sorts" and "all sorts of + n"? How can I correctly apply them to my paper?

Comment: Did you intentionally tag this as [foreign-phrases]?

Comment: *… industries of all sorts* would be a much better choice, if only because the original *industry* should have been plural *industries*.

There is nothing wrong - certainly not grammatically - with *You shall have gold as well, and all sorts of jewels* but that’s mere prose and the original *You shall have gold as well, and jewels of all sorts* is poetic.

None of that would mean you could conclude *n + of all sorts = all sorts of + n = n + of every sort and kind*. 

*n + of all sorts <> all sorts of + n*.

Either way *all sorts* <> *of every sort and kind* by any manner of means.

Comment: Further, *implied meaning* is not what you seem to have meant.

*Shared…* or *common meaning* would be fine but *implied* has no place here.